# Windows not booting after running update-grub and installing ubuntu-desktop from recovery mode of ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a dual boot operating system on my laptop which has a Windows and a Ubuntu Installation which was working perfectly. I accidentally uninstalled python from my Ubuntu and then a lot of applications disappeared like my terminal. Then I went into recovery mode of Ubuntu and performed `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop` and also performed update-grub. This worked and my Ubuntu started working fine.

But now my windows isn't booting and I tried startup repair which wasn't able to find the problem. I went into command prompt and then ran DISKPART to list the disk but my disk is also not recognized.

The windows partition is successfully being recognized in gparted. As the storage is not being recognized by DISKPART I cant repair from live USB or any other method available on the internet.

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Reinstalling the desktop does not put back ALL the python parts you have corrupted. A full install of Ubuntu is the common recommendation to having messed with python. Many parts of Ubuntu need the version of Python it ships with not only the DE. Have you tried to use the terminal for example?

Comment: The thing is my ubuntu is working completely fine. All the applications are working as they should now. Only problem is that my windows isnt even recognising its own disks and hence cant boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: I have tried all of the mentioned methods in that post and none seem to work.